# Need Multiple versions for same dependency for Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I know its a repetitive question on Site , but I didn't find  solution to my problem.

I have project specific dependency with multiple versions and I want all of them :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.textile</groupId>
            <artifactId>textile-client</artifactId>
            <version>431</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.textile</groupId>
        <artifactId>textile-client</artifactId>
        <version>441</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.textile</groupId>
        <artifactId>textile-client</artifactId>
        <version>451</version>
    </dependency>
```

PS : Doing migration from ANT to MAVEN. Thus ANT can support multiple versions for the same jar in lib folder.(`textile-client-431.jar,textile-client-441.jar,textile-client-451.jar`) But when migrating to MAVEN, it takes only the latest version(`textile-client-451.jar`). Is there any way to include all versions.

Comment: This does not make much sense: If they contain the same classes they would be loaded only from the first archive found in the classpath. If they contain different classes, why is it the same artifact?

Comment: put them into separate modules? and yeah, better explain why you want to do so.

Comment: @ryenus How to put them in separate modules.

Comment: see this: http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/, though you should just google it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Maven does not allow that. Maven will only resolve one dependency and will avoid the other ones.

I do not test it, but I remember to read about two possibilities:

First, you can specify different profiles, and in each profile you can specify a dependency with a version. Something like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>431</id>
        <activation>
            ...
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.textile</groupId>
            <artifactId>textile-client</artifactId>
            <version>431</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>431</id>
        <activation>
            ...
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.textile</groupId>
            <artifactId>textile-client</artifactId>
            <version>431</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

Second, I read something some time ago about OSGI, maybe it could help you to take a look. http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html